# Sidebar Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Just a quick question. Does any of you know of a good plugin to make a sidebar using jQuery ? I'm not talking about CMS-style sidebar (WP, Drupal, ...), but more like Youtube's or Grooveshark's playlist on the bottom of the screen.

I found something http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQuerySideBar/, but it doesn't exactly correspond to what I'm looking for. I'm sure it can be modified, but if something already exists, it would be better. I don't really want to reinvent the wheel...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [one](http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/sliding-side-bar-scriptaculous/#). Download code form [here](http://www.parrisstudios.com/?p=339)

Comment: Thanks man ! Exactly what I needed ! With 2 changes in CSS, it does exactly what I need